# Spring Kafka library consumer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, aws-msk

we're using containerized Spring boot application which connects to `MSK Apache Kafka 2.8.2` using this library `org.springframework.kafka 2.6.3`
we got a lot of errors, as example.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'java.lang.IllegalStateException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1394)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Some partitions are unassigned but all consumers are at maximum capacity
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractStickyAssignor.constrainedAssign(AbstractStickyAssignor.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractStickyAssignor.assign(AbstractStickyAssignor.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor.assign(CooperativeStickyAssignor.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractPartitionAssignor.assign(AbstractPartitionAssignor.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:590)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:689)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1400(AbstractCoordinator.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:602)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:575)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1132)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:412)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:419)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:359)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1268)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1238)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1054)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Before these storm of errors we got the following errors, but just few of them

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1134)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:999)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1504)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2351)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2346)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.ackImmediate(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1471)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processAck(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1450)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2500(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:450)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ConsumerAcknowledgment.acknowledge(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2484)
    at com.welikan.core.event_handler.api.BaseAcknowledgingTenantEventHandler.handle(BaseAcknowledgingTenantEventHandler.java:38)
    at com.welikan.core.common.services.kafka.impl.KafkaTenantTopicServiceImpl.lambda$buildOnMessageCallback$3(KafkaTenantTopicServiceImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AcknowledgingMessageListener.onMessage(AcknowledgingMessageListener.java:33)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2033)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2006)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1943)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1883)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1777)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1149)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1054)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Also in cloudwatch logs we have a lot of rebalances events.

For consumer we have the following configuration:

```
max.poll.records = 50
partition.assignment.strategy = CooperativeStickyAssignor
```

We tried to increase `max.poll.intervall` from 5 minutes up to 10 minutes.